# x86 assembly multiply and divide instruction operands, 16-bit and higher

Tags: assembly, x86, division, multiplication

I'm rather confused about how the multiply and divide operations work in x86 assembly. For example, the code below doesn't seem too difficult since deals with 8-bit.

8-Bit Multiplication:

```
; User Input:
; [num1], 20
; [num2] , 15

mov    ax, [num1]    ; moves the 8 bits into AL
mov    bx, [num2]    ; moves the 8 bits into BL

mul    bl            ; product stored in AX

print  ax
```

But what happens when you want to multiply two 16-bit numbers? How would one multiply two 16 bit numbers the same way as it has been done with the 8 bit numbers?

I'm confused as to what registers the values would be stored in. Would they be stored in AL and AH or would it simply store the 16-bit number in AX. To show what I mean:

```
; User Input:
; [num1], 20
; [num2], 15

mov    eax, [num1]    ; Does this store the 16-bit number in AL and AH or just in AX
mov    ebx, [num2]    ; Does this store the 16-bit number in BL and BH or just in BX

mul    ???            ; this register relies on where the 16-bit numbers are stored

print  eax
```

Could someone elaborate a bit on how the multiplying and dividing works? (specifically with 16-bit and 32-bit numbers? Would I need to rotate bits if the values are stored in the lower AL and AH?

Or can one simply `mov num1` and `num2` into `ax` and `bx` respectively and then multiply them to get the product in `eax`?

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A quick glance at the [documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) shows that there are 4 possible operand sizes for `MUL`.  The inputs and outputs are summarized in a handy table:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Operand Size | Source 1 | Source 2   | Destination |
------------------------------------------------------
| Byte         | AL       | r/m8       | AX          |
| Word         | AX       | r/m16      | DX:AX       |
| Doubleword   | EAX      | r/m32      | EDX:EAX     |
| Quadword     | RAX      | r/m64      | RDX:RAX     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I looked at that, and was aware of where the value is stored after the `mul`. I'm wondering if, when I store the value in `eax` (prior to `mul`) if it stores it in the lower bits (AL and AH) rather than the higher bits (AX). If it does store them in the lower bits, am I able to rotate them to AX and then just multiply AX and BX and print out the answer (I believe it would be in EAX)?

Comment: If you store a value in `eax` it's in *all* of `eax`.  I'm not sure I understand.  I think you might be confusing which parts of `eax` are `ah`, `al`, and `ax`, too.  You can see the chart in volume 1 of the same documentation.  In particular, `ax` refers to the same 16 bits as `ah:al`, not the "upper" 16-bits of `eax`.

Comment: Ah you are correct, that is what I was confused about. So essentially what I would want to do is multiply `AX` by `BX` and my product should be in `EAX`?

Comment: Close, but the product will be in `DX:AX`.  Check the table in my answer.

Comment: So multiplying two 16-bit numbers doesn't make a 32-bit number? (This would also be why I was confused with the chart. I thought multiplying two 16-bit numbers would make a 32-bit number)

Comment: Sure it does - DX is 16 bits, and AX is 16 bits.  That makes DX:AX a 32-bit number. 16+16=32, right?

Comment: Wow, sometimes I think I'm half blind when trying to read documentation. I assumed that meant it stored the values in AX `OR` DX not both. Last question before I accept your answer: So if I want to print this out, would I move DX into EAX rotate left and then move AX in as well and print EAX?

Comment: AX is already there - it's the bottom 16 bits of EAX.  You would need to move the DX half up into the top half of EAX, yes.