# Dividing two numbers in nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to divide two numbers in `nasm` after taking a input. Here is my code-

```
%include        'functions.asm'

SECTION .bss
b2:      RESB    4
SECTION .text
global  _start

_start:

    mov edx,4
    mov ecx,b2
    mov ebx,0
    mov eax,3
    int 80h

    mov eax,35
    mov ebx,5
    div ebx 
    call    iprintLF
```

Here is my `functions.asm` file-

```
iprint:
    push    eax             ; preserve eax on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    ecx             ; preserve ecx on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    edx             ; preserve edx on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    esi             ; preserve esi on the stack to be restored after function runs
    mov     ecx, 0  

divideLoop:
    inc     ecx             ; count each byte to print - number of characters
    mov     edx, 0          ; empty edx
    mov     esi, 10         ; mov 10 into esi
    idiv    esi             ; divide eax by esi
    add     edx, 48         ; convert edx to it's ascii representation - edx holds the remainder after a divide instruction
    push    edx             ; push edx (string representation of an intger) onto the stack
    cmp     eax, 0          ; can the integer be divided anymore?
    jnz     divideLoop      ; jump if not zero to the label divideLoop

printLoop:
    dec     ecx             ; count down each byte that we put on the stack
    mov     eax, esp        ; mov the stack pointer into eax for printing
    call    sprint          ; call our string print function
    pop     eax             ; remove last character from the stack to move esp forward
    cmp     ecx, 0          ; have we printed all bytes we pushed onto the stack?
    jnz     printLoop       ; jump is not zero to the label printLoop

    pop     esi             ; restore esi from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    pop     edx             ; restore edx from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    pop     ecx             ; restore ecx from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    pop     eax             ; restore eax from the value we pushed onto the stack at the start
    ret

;------------------------------------------
; void iprintLF(Integer number)
; Integer printing function with linefeed (itoa)
iprintLF:
    call    iprint          ; call our integer printing function

    push    eax             ; push eax onto the stack to preserve it while we use the eax register in this function
    mov     eax, 0Ah        ; move 0Ah into eax - 0Ah is the ascii character for a linefeed
    push    eax             ; push the linefeed onto the stack so we can get the address
    mov     eax, esp        ; move the address of the current stack pointer into eax for sprint
    call    sprint          ; call our sprint function
    pop     eax             ; remove our linefeed character from the stack
    pop     eax             ; restore the original value of eax before our function was called
    ret

;------------------------------------------
; int slen(String message)
; String length calculation function
slen:
    push    ebx
    mov     ebx, eax

nextchar:
    cmp     byte [eax], 0
    jz      finished
    inc     eax
    jmp     nextchar

finished:
    sub     eax, ebx
    pop     ebx
    ret

;------------------------------------------
; void sprint(String message)
; String printing function
sprint:
    push    edx
    push    ecx
    push    ebx
    push    eax
    call    slen

    mov     edx, eax
    pop     eax

    mov     ecx, eax
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     80h

    pop     ebx
    pop     ecx
    pop     edx
    ret
```

This is the output I get-
`3435973843` after division. Why is this happening? If I remove the portion of code where I take input and just  do div, it works.

Comment: You forgot to zero `edx` before `div`, as usual.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks a lot. I spent an hour trying to figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [x86 assembly multiply and divide instruction operands, 16-bit and higher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794416/x86-assembly-multiply-and-divide-instruction-operands-16-bit-and-higher)